# Ternary toggle in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to set the order of something using options from a dropdown. I'm putting the order into a variable and I'm trying to use that variable to decide which option to have as selected but for some reason it won't work. Can anyone work out what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<option value="DESC" <? ($comment_order == "DESC" ? "selected" : "");?>>Descending</option>
<option value="ASC" <? ($comment_order == "ASC" ? "selected" : "");?>>Ascending</option>
```

Comment: Define "it won't work", what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: If your server isn't configured to use PHP short-tags (which arguably it shouldn't be) then you'll need to open you PHP code with `<?php` rather than just `<?`

Comment: It just displays the options as if the pho wasn't there.

Comment: My server does use short tags. Over half the page is php using short tags and this is the only snippet not working.

Comment: @BartFriederichs has already nailed it - you're not echoing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement does not output anything. You want to put `echo` before it:

```
 <? echo ($comment_order == "DESC" ? "selected" : "");?>
```

Comment: or `<?= $comment_order == "DESC" ? "selected" : ""; ?>`

Comment: @CD001 I don't know if the `<?= ?>` tags also allow for more code than just a variable.

Comment: Yeah they do, it's exactly the same as `<?php echo`

Comment: I think the heat must getting to me. How on Earth did I miss that? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

if you are posting them here is the code

let me know if there is an error or something

```
<option value="DESC" <? ($comment_order == $_POST['selectname'] ? "selected" : "");?>>Descending</option>
<option value="ASC" <? ($comment_order == $_POST['selectname'] ? "selected" : "");?>>Ascending</option>
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will either select all or none of the options.